# index of a file in git has been deleted in Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Can someone tell me what does it mean when the index of a file in git has been deleted? Those files are flagged in red in my VS Code, but I still can modify the file and push the changes to a remote repository which will reflect those changes. I think this all happened when I cleared the cache in git with the command  "git rm --cached . " . I accidentally pushed the node_modules folder to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it sounds like you've deleted all the files from the index.  `git rm --cached .` does exactly that.  The index holds changes that are staged for commit, so next time you commit, you'll delete all the files from your repository.

That isn't very useful and it probably isn't what you wanted to do.  `git rm --cached` tells Git that you should leave the files you've mentioned (in this case, everything under the current directory and below) in the working tree, but stage them for deletion from Git.

Now that you've done that, you should look at what files are untracked, such as your `node_modules` folder.  Anything that you don't want Git to track and commit should be added to your `.gitignore` (for example, `node_modules/`).  Once you've listed all the patterns that you want to ignore in your `.gitignore` file, you'll want to run `git add .`, which will re-add all of the files to the index.

Then you can run `git status` and make sure that all the changes are the way you want them to be.  If you end up having added things that you still don't want, you can run `git rm --cached FILE`, where `FILE` is one or more files or directories that you specifically want to not commit.  You can then add appropriate entries to `.gitignore` that mention those paths.

Note that anything that's already staged in the index isn't affected by `.gitignore`, so you'll need to unstage it specifically (using a restricted `git rm --cached`) as mentioned above.